# Internet won't connect

Tags: windows-7

I have a Netgear modem/router that has 2 computers directly plugged by ethernet cord to it and use the wireless connection for an iPad.  The main computer using Windows 7 has connection to the Internet, but will not connect using Internet Explorer or Safari.  The IP Address is valid and not the same as the other desktop computer.  I have taken computer to be serviced and when it is connected to their modem, the Internet comes up just fine.  I take the computer home, and there is no connection.  What can I do?

Comment: Try setting an internal static ip adress [Guide](http://portforward.com/networking/static-win7.htm) and set the dns servers to 8.8.8.8 Try again. Also, more details would be great.

Comment: Try resetting your Router Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to configure IP Address properly.

Configure IPv4 address,Subnet mask,default gateway, preferred DNS and alternate DNS Server address.

Your Internet provider should help you for configuring this.